# "Interval" field not supported by Eventlogfile object (in Enterprise edition org)

Tags: permissions, fields, workbench, enterprise, eventlogfile

I am using Salesforce **Enterprise edition**, and I have the "**System Administrator**" profile assigned to me, which has all the permission related to Read, Modify All data, View Event log files, and API enabled.

when I Query workbench with SOQL Query: **https://myinstanceURL/services/data/v41.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+EventLogFile+WHERE+Interval+=+'Hourly'**

I received an error saying **"Interval field is not supported by EventLogFile"**.

**Please note that this issue occurs in Enterprise edition org (*and REST API call seems to work fine in Developer Org*).**

Then I checked the standard and custom objects and fields to verify them in the workbench "info tab".

On choosing the object "**EventLogFile**", I didn't find the field "Interval".

[image]

Do we need any other permission for accessing the Interval field in the salesforce enterprise edition? Because in the developer edition I am able to find the "Interval" field for the "EventLogFile" object by default.
[image]

In both the account the API version being used in 50.0 during login.

Whereas in the documentation, I could find that the "**Interval**" field is available from API version 37.0 and later.
[image]

Due to this, I am unable to query hourly logs, but when the field, Interval is not used in the query, I could find logs.

Please, could anyone tell me where I am wrong? And how to get access to the "Interval" field in Enterprise edition.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have tried and I was able to use your REST URL & execute it in my dev org without any issues. What is the result if you execute a SOQL instead of REST API?

Comment: Thank you for your response, In my dev org it's working fine, when it comes to enterprise one, I am having issues with the field "Interval" for Eventlogfile object.

Comment: Okay. I don't have access to an Enterprise edition org at the moment to try it out. Let's see if any of the other members in this forum are able to provide any information on this.

Comment: do you have shield Event Monitoring licensed in your EE? (In our EE org, we do, and field `Interval` is viisible)

Comment: @cropredy I don't have a Shield Event Monitoring License in my EE org. I will check after getting a license and update. Thank you.

Comment: @BharatD any update on this,were you able to get the correct license or subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was in comments but nobody posted it as an answer.

You need [Shield Event Monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_shield.htm&type=5) license.